# How can i find the parent of the cursor in a binary tree without using a parent reference node

Tags: java, binary-tree

I am trying move cursor to it's parent node in a binary tree. I want to do it recursively without using a keeping a node to keep track of the parent. I think my base/stoping case is correct but I believe the last two if statement is wrong. Im not sure on how to go about it. Any advice will be helpful. Thank you.

```
   public void cursorToParent()
{
    TreeNode parent = root;
    if(cursor == root )
        return;
    if(parent.getLeft().equals(cursor) || parent.getRight().equals(cursor) )
        cursor = parent;
    else
        if(parent.getLeft()!=null)
        {
            parent = parent.getLeft();
            cursorToParent();
        }
        if(parent.getLeft()!=null)
        {
            parent = parent.getLeft();
            cursorToParent();
        }

}
```

Comment: You would need to pass argument to `cursorToParent` method. For better help, Post an example of what is expected output. Thanks!

Comment: I am making a tree where the cursor moves based on yes or no answer(left or right of tree). for example if the root is red , yes(right node) = apple , no(left node) = orange. So if my cursor is at orange right now. When i call my method I want the cursor to go to the parent of orange, which is red. @iNan

Answer (score 0):

It's needed to pass the `current` processing node to the method. So there has to be method `cursorToParentImpl()` which will be called with `root` from the former method:

```
public boolean cursorToParentImpl(TreeNode current)
{
    if(cursor == current )
        return false;
    if(current.getLeft () == cursor || current.getRight() == cursor) {
        cursor = current;
        return true;
    }
    else { // note the missing parenthesis too
        if(current.getLeft()!=null) {
            if (cursorToParentImpl(current.getLeft()))
                return true;
        }
        if(current.getRight()!=null) {
            if (cursorToParentImpl(current.getRight()))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And call it:

```
public void cursorToParent()
{
    if (cursor == root)
        return;
    cursorToParentImpl(root);
}
```

Also you may avoid calling `equals()` and just use `==` operator as here it should rather compare the reference to the nodes.

Comment: I tried what you have, it just returns the cursor location

Comment: the second recursive call that branches right has an incorrect guard, it should check `current.getRight()!=null`. it currently calls `getLeft()`.

Comment: @jackiechan : it could be because of equals. I changed it to `==`. And thanks robbmj, fixed.

Comment: Yep thanks alot! ! its cause of the .equals() . What is the difference between == and equals ? when I thought if im comparing objects i have to use equals(). @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000

Comment: @jackiechen : `equals()` compares the content (if two objects have the same value) while `==` compares that the objects are exactly the same instances. Usually we use `equals()` because we want to know whether they contain the same value but here `==` is sufficient as it's internal structure where each node exists only once.

Comment: oooo Makes sense! Thanks alot! (: @ZbynekVyskovsky-kvr000